# How do I make an environment on CentOS 6.5 where I can use the latest shell, diff, vim, etc.?

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I ssh to a CentOS 6.5 system, where I have root privileges.

I know that CentOS is intentionally limited to very old versions of the kernel and the commands so that software running on it, especially server software, is very reliable. I don't want to interfere with any of that.

But while I'm logged in as myself, I want all the commands I use to be the latest versions that can possibly run on this version of CentOS.

To that end I want to make a folder tree called /latest that has its own bin, etc, lib, and so on, so that with my PATH and ld environment variables set to point into this tree, I can run the latest versions of coreutils and other software. Especially, I want to be able to use yum to keep the tree up to date (without touching the CentOS versions of anything). More or less like this:

```
PATH=/latest/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
yum update
yum install zsh
```

It seems to me that it must be possible to make a script that would set up a /latest folder like this so that yum can take it from there, but I can't find anything like that anywhere.

What sort of rabbit hole might this approach lead to?

Comment: yum is intended for software management for the currently running CentOS version - not arbitrary newer individual software package releases(which usually only come in source code form)- so trying to use yum for that will lead you down a rabbit hole.

Comment: There was once a commercially-supported meta-distro intended for just this purpose, but I want to say they folded some time back.

Answer (score 0):

You could install a recent Linux distribution in a `chroot`-ed environment (perhaps using `schroot` if it exists).

You could also compile recent versions of software from their source code. You probably want to have a directory `$HOME/soft/` then

```
 configure --prefix=$HOME/soft
```

You might consider ugrading the distribution on your server (if you have the appropriate permissions from the machine owner).

Comment: I used the Modules system to maintain different versions of compilers. Well aware of that. But it's not a good solution for dozens of packages.

Comment: I even wrote a pretty extensive script to make it a lot easier to build and install an [Environment Module](http://modules.sourceforge.net)